# Adding adjacent characters in a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-studio-2012, for-loop

So I am trying to create a code to add adjacent numbers within a vector.
I have actually figured out the challenge and managed to produce code that does what I want, however while playing around with it I found something kind of puzzling that I don't understand.

a brief explanation or what I was trying to achieve:
The user should input however many integers they want.
those numbers should be stored in the same order in the array.

In this example lets use the integers [1],[2],[3],[4] - because they are easy to add.

the code below uses two for loops, with the first index (i1) starting at holder[0] and the other 
loop index (i2) starting at holder[1]. this is so that the two indexes are always next to each other.

after I output the sum of holder[0] + holder[1] (which equals 3)
both indexes should be incremented by two, which would move their positions to holder[2] and holder [3], after they have been incremented the total of their values should be 7. because holder[2] and holder[3] have the values 3 and 4 respectively.

with this thought out my output should be : 3 7
however when the code below executes my output is: 3 5 5 7

I don't  understand what is going on behind the scenes? Can anyone explain what I've done wrong

when I enter the code below:

```
vector<int> holder;
int number;

while (cin >> number)
{
    holder.push_back(number);
}

for(decltype(holder.size()) i1 = 0; i1 <= holder.size() - 2; i1 = i1 + 2)
{
    for(decltype(holder.size()) i2 = 1; i2 <= holder.size() - 1; i2 = i2 + 2)
    {
        cout << holder[i1] + holder[i2] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using two nested loops; you should use only one.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need two loops. That's just confusing the logic. If you just want to print the pairwise sums, make that explicit:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < holder.size() - 1; i += 2) {
    cout << holder[i] + holder[i+1] << " ";
}
```

That will, explicitly, print `holder[0] + holder[1]`, then `holder[2] + holder[3]`, etc.

Comment: I think he wants holder[i] + holder[i+1] followed by holder[i+2] + holder[i+3]

Comment: Ah! well I feel pretty crappy now. I always make things harder than they need to be! Adam is correct on this one but you answer was definitely what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should only need one loop to accomplish this task:

```
vector<int> holder;
int number;

while(cin >> number)
{
  holder.push_back(number);
}

for(unsigned i=0; i<holder.size()-1; i+=2)
{
  cout << holder[i] + holder[i+1] << " ";
}
```

Also, using `decltype()` as you did seems unnecessary, but that could be because you're abstracting this question from more complicated code.

Comment: If you use `auto`, it will deduce `i` as `int`... so you'll get a signed/unsigned comparison warning on `holder.size()`. That's probably why OP used `decltype`.

Comment: So you may use suffix `U` (or `u`) for unsigned: `auto i = 0U;`